# JOGL runs extremely slow from a jar file on other machines.

Tags: java, performance, jogl

I am currently messing around with JOGL and JBullet, with some success. I'd like to share what I've created with my friends. I created a jar file and a .bat to open it with the argument -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true. The jar runs perfectly on my machine. It opens and runs on my friends system and my laptop, but at an **extremely** low frame rate. What is the cause of this and how can I fix it?

Also for some reason it loads the wrong textures for an object, again only when ran on another system. They are both Windows 8.1 x64 systems. The graphics drivers of all systems are up to date as well. This is really disconcerting because i want to be able to distribute this program, even if only amongst friends. .

Comment: Maybe its a case of "it works on my machine"? Do you have anything on your machine that could be different to the testing machines? Can you test on more devices?

Comment: My development machine utilizes ATI graphics while my laptop uses Nvidia. I seem to suspect that the jar is not running using the graphics card on the laptop and is run solely in the CPU. I don't know how to confirm this, though all the benchmarks on the laptop are as good if not better than the dev macine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was using GLJpanel as opposed to using GLCanvas. GLJpanel is lightweight and doest support the complexity as does GLCanvas.

Answer (score 0):

Check the specifications of each machine. Even brand matters here. Update all the drivers , Java , use the latest versions of your libraries. Do some benchmarking tests. Check for any overclock settings , sometimes it may be hard to find out. Check out the temperatures(including coolers and case ventilation). Check out any 3rd party software used to accelerate stuff (indeed , some of them work). Check out the antivirus software , it can cause trouble too . Check out the OS , (even the small updates) , finally , be sure that there are no other processes running (than the basic ones.)

Check again drivers and OS , it may be not what you think.

Comment: I've done all this 10x over. I did another update Just before this comment. I have a feeling it has something to do with Intel's graphics processing taking over when it should be the Nvida GPU. I cannot confirm this though.

Comment: You shall at least tell us onboard/GPU of each PC.